# Next key in softkeyboard not working in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I am using webview in my app. There are many edit texts in webview. I need to focus the next edit text in the webview when I click on "Next" button in the soft keyboard. Is it possible? Then how can I do that?

Answer (score -2):

it is possible by editing in your layout file, just set the XML attributes 
   android:imeOptions="actionNext"                                                             for your all EditText boxes and                                          android:imeOptions="actionDone" for the last one. working in my Webview

See: [android:imeOptions documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)

Comment: but we dont have the code of edittexts inside the webview. Then how can we set the imeOptions?

Comment: sorry for late reply. could you please elaborate . such description about your code?